# How to find $f(x)$ in this situation?

Tags: calculus

The problem is: if $f(-1)=5$ and $f’(x)=(x^2+3x)f(x)$ for all $x$, find $f''(-1)$

I know that I must use the product rule to find $f''$, but I am not sure how to find $f(x)$ in the first place just given $f(-1)=5$, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You don't need an explicit formula for $f(x)$.  Try finding the second derivative then use what you know about function notation to evaluate it.

Comment: How would I be able to find the second derivative without having a value for f(x) in the product rule?

Comment: The derivative of $f(x)$ as you need it can simply be written as $f'(x)$.

Comment: "How would I be able to find the second derivative without having a value for f(x) in the product rule? "  Why do you need a *value* for the product rule  $[f(x)g(x)]'=f'(x)g(x) +f(x)g'(x)$  so $f''(x) = (2x+3)f(x) + (x^2+3)f'(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align} f'(x)&=(x^2+3x)f(x)\Rightarrow f'(-1)=((-1)^2+3(-1))f(-1)=-10\\
f''(x)&=(2x+3)f(x) +(x^2+3x) f'(x) \\
f''(-1)&=(2(-1)+3)f(-1)+((-1)^2+3(-1))f'(-1)\\
f''(-1)&=5+20=\boxed{25}\end{align}

Comment: I am down to (1)(f(-1)+1+(-3)(f’(-1)), not sure where to go now since I dont know the value of f’(-1)

Comment: You know what $f'(x)$ is, since it had been defined for you.

Comment: So would my final answer be f”(x)=6+(-3)(x^2+3x)(f(x))?

Comment: Wait that can’t be right, I am still not sure what I am supposed to do with the f’(-1) since only f’(x) is defined and not f’(-1)

Comment: If you know $f'(x)$, you know $f'(-1)$.  I've edited the solution into my answer.

Comment: Oh, so all I needed to do was plug -1 into the f’ equation. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Yes; precisely what I was implying by talking about _function notation_ in a different comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well $f'(x) = (x^2 + 3x)f(x)$ so by product rule

$f''(x) = (2x + 3)f(x) + (x^2+3x)f'(x)$.

Replacce $f'(x)$ with $(x^2+3x)f(x)$ to get

$f''(x) = (2x + 3)f(x) + (x^2+3x)^2f(x)$

Just plug in $x =-1$ and we get

$f''(-1) = (-2+3)f(-1) + ((-1)^2+3(-1))^2f(-1)= 1*5 + (-2)^2*5= 25$.